# "unable to simplify to float approximation" error in Sage on calling a function

Tags: sagemath

I have following python code in Sage:

```
%python
import math

T = 2.0 * math.pi
a = 1.0 / 4.0

def SumT(t, n):
    global T
    global a

    sum = 0

    if n < 0:
        return 0
    else:
        for i in range (1, n+1):
            sum = sum + ( (1.0 / (2.0 * i - 1.0)) * math.sin((2.0 * (2.0 * i - 1.0) * math.pi * t) / T) )
        return (4.0 / math.pi) * sum

t = var('t')
p = plot(SumT(t, 1), (t, 0, 1))
show(p)
```

Calling a function `plot(SumT(t, 1), (t, 0, 1))` gives following error:

```
unable to simplify to float approximation
```

I've already looked for same problems in other threads and posts: seems that this error should be fixed with formula simplification, but I don't know how to simplify it.

The formula itself:

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}S(t;n) & = & \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2i-1}\sin\frac{2(2i-1)\pi t}{T}\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE** The problem is fixed if use pure Sage without python math import:

```
T = 2.0 * pi
a = 1.0 / 4.0

def SumT(t, n):
    global T
    global a

    sum = 0

    if n < 0:
        return 0
    else:
        for i in range (1, n+1):
            sum = sum + ( (1.0 / (2.0 * i - 1.0)) * sin((2.0 * (2.0 * i - 1.0) * pi * t) / T) )
        return (4.0 / pi) * sum

t = var('t')
show(plot(SumT(t, 1), (t, 0, 1)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fixed if use pure Sage without python math import:

```
T = 2.0 * pi
a = 1.0 / 4.0

def SumT(t, n):
    global T
    global a

    sum = 0

    if n < 0:
        return 0
    else:
        for i in range (1, n+1):
            sum = sum + ( (1.0 / (2.0 * i - 1.0)) * sin((2.0 * (2.0 * i - 1.0) * pi * t) / T) )
        return (4.0 / pi) * sum

t = var('t')
show(plot(SumT(t, 1), (t, 0, 1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with

```
t = var('t')
```

I don't know what you were getting at but t needs to be a number to produce a result.

Additionally, I had to replace pi to math.pi.  And I personally wouldn't use global variables.  I rewrote the code (I think your calculation is correct though!):

```
%python
import math

def SumT(t, n):
    T = 2.0 * math.pi
    a = 1.0 / 4.0
    sum = 0

    if n < 0:
        return 0
    else:
        for i in range (1, n+1):
            sum = sum + ((1.0 / (2.0 * i - 1.0)) * math.sin((2.0 * (2.0 * i - 1.0) * math.pi * t) / T) )
        return (4.0 / math.pi) * sum

p = list_plot([(r,SumT(t=r, n=10).n()) for r in srange(-1, 1, 0.1, include_endpoint=True)], plotjoined=True)
show(p)
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear enough: the final goal is to plot this function (I also made these changes in the post): `p = plot(SumT(t, 1), (t, 0, 1))
show(p)`

Comment: I've never used sage python so I'm out of my depth.  But what I gathered is sage "evaluates expressions by coercing to float I.E. plot calls 'float(SumT)'".  Or the expression is too complicated for it to evaluate.  I was able to get it to somewhat work with list_plot.

Comment: The problem is fixed if use pure Sage, without python math import. But thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is somewhat deeper and I think it's a bug, rather than a feature. I have tried the following in a Sage IPython notebook at [CoCalc](https://cocalc.com):

Cell 1:

```
t = var('t')
plot(cos(t),(t, -pi, pi)  # works
```

Cell 2:

```
import math
plot(math.cos(t),(t, -pi, pi)  # raises TypeError("unable to simplify to float approximation")
```

Cell 3:

```
plot(math.cos, (x, -pi, pi)) # works
```

Cell 4:

```
plot(math.cos, (-pi,pi)) # this also works
```

Cell 5:

```
plot(math.cos(x), (x, -pi, pi)) # raises TypeError like in Cell 2
```

Basically if you want to plot a function using a named argument (`x`, `t`, whatever), then you must use the "SAGE version" of that function. The standard Python functions in the `math` package can be plotted *only if the name of the function* is passed to `plot`.

Or so I think. In any case this is rather confusing.